# Calculate double integral on the specific field

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Calculate integral
$\int\int_D \frac{dxdy}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$

$ D=\{(x,y)\in R^{2} : x^2+y^2 \le1, -x \le y, x+1 \le y\} $

I draw a graph and this is a little part of a disk. As I calculate
$x \in (-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, 0), y\in(\frac{1}{2},1)$

I calculate it in this equations: 
$x+1=-x$

$-x= \sqrt{1-x^2}$

Which is limit of this part of a disk.

My question is how to calculate next? Do I need any parametrization or not?

Comment: yes you need to parametrize.

Answer (score 1):

Use polar coordinates. The region becomes
$$
\frac{\pi}{2}\le\theta\le\frac{3\,\pi}{4},\quad \frac{1}{\sin\theta-\cos\theta}\le r\le1.
$$

Comment: Thank you! I did it but I don't know why $\frac{1}{\sin\theta-\cos\theta}\le r$ ?

Comment: I calculate it this way:
$ r \cos \theta +1 \le r => \frac{1}{1- \cos \theta} \le r $

Comment: It should be $r\cos\theta+1\le r\sin\theta$.

Comment: True! I am so blind! Thank you very much!!